# mediatr - handler are not being found

Tags: .net, mediatr

My solution has the following structure:

```
awesome-project
   Awesome.Project.App
     Program.cs
   Awesome.Project.Domain
     Commands/
     Handlers/
```

I am using mediatr in a console application but it's throwing an exception when I try to call `.Send()`:

> Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (No service for type 'MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Awesome.Project.Domain.Commands.RequestBillCommand,System.String]' has been registered.)

And I have declared added mediatr to services:

```
using Awesome.Project.Domain.Commands;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using MediatR;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Awesome.Project.App {
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Run().Wait();            
        }

        private static async Task Run()
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);
            var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

            var mediator = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();
            var command = new RequestBillCommand();
            await mediator.Send(command);
        }

        public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly));            
        }

    }
}
```

My command class:

```
    public class RequestBillCommand : IRequest<string>
    {
     ...

     }
```

The handler:

```
public class RequestBillHandler : IRequestHandler< RequestBillCommand, string>
    { }
```

Any idea what is missing to register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handlers are not being registered because they are not part of the same assembly `Program` is in. They live in the `Awesome.Project.Domain` assembly.

Add all the required assemblies in the `RegisterServicesFromAssembly` call.

Comment: What Should I do? Im new to .net

Comment: A quick fix is to just get the assembly from a type just like you did with `Program`.             `services.AddMediatR(cfg => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(new [] { typeof(Program).Assembly), typeof(RequestBillCommand).Assembly});`

Comment: Works like a charming! Tyvm

Answer (score 0):

In the future, and a tip to anyone else with this issue, wrap your:
await mediator.Send(command);

in a try/catch

This should show the issue, most likely to be a DI issue